# how to assign first loop to second loop and so on in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

i have a table Permission which has permission name, type, entity and I like to display it in the table while creating Role
[image]

I pass three variables to create a page from controllers from one Class Permission

```
    $types=Permission::select('type')->groupBy('type')->get();
    $entities=Permission::select('entity')->groupBy('entity')->get();
    $permission=Permission::select('id','name')->get();
```

now how to display the following if Type=Admin, only display the following Entity and permission.
here is the model of permission

```
    class Permission extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,Uuids;
 protected $fillable = ['id','name','type','entity'];
      public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permission_role');
    }
     
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Type=Admin" - don't you want to just filter like that: `Permission::select('type')->where('type', 'Admin')->groupBy('type')->get()`?

Comment: and how about other types , there are more than 7 types in my sitution

Comment: Okay, I bet, I got that paragraph wrong. You probably need [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: You didn't mention roles before. How do they fit in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

your models:

```php
class Type extends Model
{
    public function entities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Entity::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Entity extends Model
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

your blade view:

```
<table>
    @foreach($types as $type)
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">{{ $type->type }}</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($type->entities as $entity)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $entity->entity }}</th>
                @foreach($entity->permissions as $permission)
                    <td>{{ $permission->name }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: i try with one class Permission (name, entity, type) is that possible to do, only in permission class

Comment: $types=Permission::select('type')->groupBy('type')->get();
    $entities=Permission::select('entity')->groupBy('entity')->get();
    $permission=Permission::select('id','name')->get();

Comment: I bet it's not but it depends on your setup. For that to know, you'd have to share your Permission model's code.

Comment: class Permission extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,Uuids;
     protected $fillable = ['id','name','type','entity'];

      public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permission_role');
    }
     
}

Comment: Could you please put it in your question for better readability?

Comment: "i try with one class Permission" - why does it have to be one class? That'd mean, your table is not normalized which is considered bad programming.